converting a custom MAkefile rule to CmakeLists.txt
I have a Makefile which passes a define to each built target, by using the following rules:
GET_SOURCE_ID = `grep $< $(SOURCE_IDS_LIST)| cut -f 1`

%.o: %.c $(HEADERS) $(SOURCE_IDS_LIST)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DSOURCE_ID=$(GET_SOURCE_ID) -c $< -o $@

$(SOURCE_IDS_LIST) is a numbered list of source files, so $(GET_SOURCE_ID) retrieves a unique number which is passed as a flag to the preprocessor. I am trying to convert this for use in a CMake based build system. I guess it is something to do with target_compile_definitions() or the like, but I don't yet see how to do it. Can anyone suggest a way?

There is a question about specifying compile definitions with CMake. Have you checked it and its answers?

A macro's value you specify in target_compile_definitions/compile_definitions command should be a constant, it cannot be re-evaluated during the build. If you want to specify different macro values for different source files, then you could set COMPILE_DEFINITIONS property for separate source files. See e.g. that question.

I have, but my case seems to fall between the solutions given there. I have more than one target, and yes I do not want them all to have the same flags - but I do NOT want to add each target manually. The value of the flag varies for each source file based on GET_SOURCE_ID and that is what is not clear to me. I am figuring the answer is in there somewhere but it is hard to see where. Thank you.

@Tsyvarev ok, but surely I don't have to manually enter a rule per source file? that kind of defeats the point of the whole thing.

In CMake it is perfectly OK to add each source file separately and assign different compiler definitions for it. By using foreach loops you will avoid duplication in your CMake code.

OK, thank you - I will experiment.
